# is it possible to use %vw in transform: translateX?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have something be off screen just a bit, whatever size of the screen is so it slides in at the same time with stuff that is in another div.

This is what i tried to do but doesnt work :

```
transform: translateX(100%vw);
-webkit-transform: translateX(100%vw);
-moz-transform: translateX(100%vw);
```

Comment: You could try to look into CSS calc(),https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc , you can do simple math and use that in order to place the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did this and its exactly what i wanted, thanks!

```
    .lang {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(100vw);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(100vw);
        -moz-transform: translateX(100vw) ;

    }   
    .lang.open {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: .5s linear;
        transform: translateX(0px);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
        -moz-transform: translateX(0px) ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When using vw or vh units - you do not need the percentage sign - the definition of 1vw is 1% of the viewport width, similarly - 1vh is 1% of the veiwport height.

Incidentally - there is vmin and vmax as well,
1vmin = 1% of the smaller side of the viewport and 1vmax = 1% of the larger side of the viewport. This allows interesting effectas with smaller screens and rotating between portrait and landscape.

Also when using transform - the 100% refers to the width of the element that you are translating - so translating it by -100% moves it to the left by 100% of its own width.

```
transform: translateX(-100%);
-webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
-moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
```

The above should move the entire element to the left by  100% of its own width. To move it to the right - do not use the "-" sign.

```
transform: translateX(100%);
-webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
-moz-transform: translateX(100%);
```

Comment: is there a way not to use elements width but the width of the full page?